# Reloading Table View to Create Dynamic Label Changes iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating an app that I want to display different strings inside of a label that is within a UITableViewCell. However, I cannot use indexPath.row because the strings are in not particular order.

```
let one = "This is the first quote"
let two = "This is the second quote"

var numberOfRows = 1
var quoteNumber = 0

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let items = [one, two]

    myTableView = tableView

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cellTableViewCell
    let cellWidth = cell.frame.width
    let cellHeight = cell.frame.height

    cell.QuoteLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cellWidth/8, cellHeight/4, cellWidth/1.3, cellHeight/2)

    let item = items[quoteNumber]

    cell.QuoteLabel.text = item
    cell.QuoteLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        if quoteNumber == 0 {
            quoteNumber = 1
        }

    if numberOfRows == 1 {
        numberOfRows = 2
    }

    return cell

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
func update() {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

This code builds and runs, but when the timer I have set expires and the update function is ran, both of the two available cells change to the same label. What I am trying to do is make it so that the first cell can remain static while the newly added cell can receive the new element from the 'items' array without using indexpath.row (because the quotes that I am going to be using from the items array will be in no particular order). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your data has to be in order. How else can you display the rows properly? Your data must be indexable by indexPath. There's no getting around that fact.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `reloadData` try using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` and pass in the rows you want to reload.  This does use `indexPath`, however.  The only way I'm aware of to reload specific rows as opposed to the whole tableView is to specify the rows by index path.

Comment: I have tried using that, however it crashes with an error message saying that the second row I am trying to modify does not exist. My guess is that I would need to create it before the update, but I don't want the second row to be populated with the first row's data... Any suggestions @Hash88

Comment: what are you returning from `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`?  If that value is `1`, then your table view will only have one cell.

Comment: With `UITableView`, you don't really 'create' cells.  You should specify how many sections & rows you want in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:`,  then in `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you do create (or reuse) each cell, but the number of cells you use are not specified there.